# Как сохранять все скрины встроенными средствами Windows?

Tags: windows

На данный момент для сохранения скриншотов пользуюсь программой lightshot.
Использую в основном скрины участков, и зачастую подрезаю под размер окон.
Увидел что в Windows 11 можно вызвать окно с настройками, прямоугольник, лассо, окно.
Я знаю что в Windows есть возможность сохранять скриншоты на диск командой <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> по пути C:\Users\User\Pictures\Screenshots, но это работает только для всего экрана.
Можно ли как-то сделать сохранение на рабочий стол скринов участков и окон после вызова команды <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>?
Да и почему до сих пор Microsoft не научится делать грамотно, ну или хотябы слушать пользователей...?

Answer (score 0):

Стандартная программа Windows "Ножницы" умеет делать скриншот выбранного окна, весь экран, произвольный прямоугольник либо произвольную форму

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> делает то же самое, только сохраняет скриншоты не на рабочий стол, а в буфер

Ну да, такая винда, что поделать

Comment: win-shift-s очень удобно, если нужно сколхозничать. я бы на месте microsoft просто бы 2 режима сделал: сохранять в clipboard или на диск

Comment: @return наверное и ножницы можно настроить чтобы они сохраняли в определённую папку, хотя нет, там нужно нажимать CTRL + S. Я сам пользуюсь бесплатным яндекс - диском, он тоже умеет сохранять выбранную область прямоугольной формы

Comment: alex, Windows "Ножницы" умеет сохранять после выделения, есть ли горячая клавиша для вызова ножниц? Можно ли пропустить окно ножниц и сохранения, и сохранить сразу на диск?

Comment: @biomotor нет, горячей клавиши для вызова ножниц нет

Comment: alex, в свойствах ярлыка можно указать горячие клавиши, и вызывать по ним. Только вот кнопка Win не распознается...